# Chromium and Chrome stored credentials are not showing up under "saved passwords"

Tags: password, password-recovery, passwd

for some reasons my already stored passwords are not visible under saved passwords, it just shows "saved passwords will appear here"

but they are there, the sql file is where it should be, chrome and Chromium behave identically:

- for new site passwords is popping up the dialog "save password", after confirming the autofill is working
- for changed passwords is popping up the dialog for change password and after autofill is correctly working

has apparently nothing to do with the keyring password, I can delete it and autofill keeps working FINE, seems Chromium was using an encrypted password while Chrome used a plain text password, I believe that was because before installing Chrome for checking it out I removed all kwallet files, (I use KDE Plasma ) reinstalling after didn't caused any change

the Chrome settings are correct and the problem appeared some upgrades ago but came to my knowledge when I needed to remember a password, now I am with Chrome  84.0.4147.125 and Chromium 85.0.4183.59

just to complete they are no on Google and sync was never activated

also interesting renaming the passwd sql file and starting Chrome or Chromium, they asked for save the credentials and then the show up, but that is no solution to the problem why the old ones are not showing up

would be very nice if somebody has an idea to solve this